# generators, python, infinite loop

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to produce a list of odd numbers using a generator (just to get a better insight into generators). I wrote the following code but, it doesn't stop running! While I expect the code stops when the condition i>n meets.
Any help is appreciated.

```
import sys
def odd(n):
    i=0    
    while True: 
        if i%2==0:
            continue
        yield i
        i+=1
        if i>n:
            return
# Here we build a generator 
g = odd(10)
while True:
    try:
        print(next(g),end=' ')
    except StopIteration:
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: When `i` is even, you never increment it. It stays even forever.

Comment: You aren't raising a stopiteration, you're just returning.

Comment: @Neil That's essentially what `return` does in a generator function.

Comment: @chepner still weird to use while loop and try/except on StopIteration instead of `for`

Comment: @CorentinLimier That doesn't really have anything to do with the question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you have two style issues in your code that make it hard to see the problem:

1. The use of `continue`. A simple `if` statement would make it easier to see which code might not execute and which code will definitely execute. `continue` is mainly useful when you have nested `if` statements making things complicated.
2. You don't utilize the `while` condition. This assumes that the `while` loop will have to execute at least once. When writing a loop, you should generally consider what happens if the loop needs to execute 0 times. What if someone passes an argument of `-1`? What if you change the initial value of `i` to 1 to save an iteration?

---

```
def odd(n):
    i = 0
    while i <= n:
        if i % 2:
            yield i
        i += 1
    # Automatically return and throw StopIteration.
```

Comment: I don't know how my code isn't formatted. It's indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: I added a hard rule to separate the code from the numbered list. I don't know why a blank line doesn't do that.

Comment: Thank you luther. Your notes were really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When `i` is even, you don't increment it, so it stays even for every subsequent iteration of the loop and never gets larger than `n`.

You want to increment `i` whether or not it is even.

```
def odd(n):
    i=0    
    while True: 
        if i%2 != 0:  # yield i only if it is odd
            yield i
        i+=1  # Increment i in either case
        if i>n:
            return
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @chepner. You are right, I had completely forgotten to increase i when it is even. Actually I was practicing some commands in python and I wanted to use continue to see how it works.